# Why can't I install tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, pip

I made sure I am on version 3.6, and I tried everything.

Here's what I tried:

```
py -m pip install tensorflow

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
PS C:\Users\skarl> pip install tensorflow
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: C:\Users\skarl\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
PS C:\Users\skarl> -m pip install --upgrade pip
-m : The term '-m' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ -m pip install --upgrade pip
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-m:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\skarl> py -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\skarl\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (23.3.2)
```

I expected it to work, but it did not. What is wrong?

Comment: TensorFlow is not yet available for Python 3.12

Answer (score 0):

Read the error messages more carefully:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
```

It looks like you're trying to install the package into a location where you're not allowed to. Perhaps you can create a virtual environment. Otherwise get an admin to help or run the terminal as admin.

```
To update, run: C:\Users\skarl\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

This says to run Python with the arguments `-m pip install --upgrade pip`, not to run the arguments as if they were a valid command, which is what you tried:

```
-m pip install --upgrade pip
```

That can't work. Either this:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

But more likely exactly what the error message suggested, using the full path to Python, as it is perhaps not on your path (which is a good thing, generally).

However, although updating pip is not a bad thing, it's unlikely to solve your issue. Look at setting up a virtual environment, or obtain the appropriate privileges to install the package.

Comment: Sorry but this answer is completely wrong, the problem is TF not being available for Python 3.12

Comment: I think the answer is correct, but you're right that it doesn't address the key issue: that TensorFlow currently is not available for 3.12. I just felt OP was missing the above, and TF will become available shortly, so anyone with issues in the future will benefit from these remarks. Feel free to post the actual issue as an additional (and possibly accepted) answer. (keep an eye on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/62003)

Comment: He already did the right thing in his last line `py -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Your answer was sure well meant, but it is confusing because it does not address the real problem (Python 3.12) in the slightest.